# How to handle many slow connections

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat8

The throughput of our web application seems to be limited by slow connections. In load tests, we easily achieve about 5000 requests/s. But in practice, we max out at about 1000 requests/s. The server isn't really under serious load, neither IO nor CPU wise. The same applies to the database. The main difference seems to be that most worker threads are slowed down by clients that cannot accept the response fast enough (often responses are several MB in size).

We hardly have any static resources. The the problem is about dynamically generated content. It's implemented with the Spring Framework. But I think it wouldn't be different for any other servlet based implementation.

So what are our options for improving throughput? Is there some sort of caching available that would quickly absorb the response, free up the worker threads and then asynchronously deliver it to the client at their speed?

We'd rather not increase the number of processing threads as they keep a database connection open for most of their processing. We're really looking for a solution where a small number of worker threads can work at full speed.

Comment: I found a description of your problem with a direction for a solution [here](http://serverfault.com/a/406684). The nginx "reverse proxy" sounds [promising](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/). If it works, let us know in an answer to your own question, I might need it one day as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes, nginx reverse proxying with buffering enabled seems what we're looking for. It'll take us some time to configure it and verify it increases our throughput in real-world circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use standard techniques such as gzip for responses.

The second one is to use asynchronous processing in Spring MVC. See [Making a Controller Method Asynchronous](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/10/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-making-a-controller-method-asynchronous/) to learn more about this.

Comment: We're already using compression for compressable data. And my understanding of asynchronous controllers is that they solve a different problem: they help if your HTTP connection with the client is idle, either because it's an event-driven server push or because the server has to forward the request to another system and wait for a long time. In our case, the client is the bottleneck. Can you describe how it can be applied for this case? Does it really buffer the output until the client has absorbed it?

Comment: Using async controllers yields ability to implement AsyncTaskExecutor with given thread pool size and queueing mechanism whereas controllers will still process new requests.
But if I understood right you should to review the architecture: 1) clustering the app, 2) replace output format to reduce network load, 3) chunked output, 4) caching by proxy (like nginx) and so on. Otherwise it is impossible to output more data than clients really can process.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. At closer look, nginx as a reverse proxy with buffering looks like a valid option (as proposed by vanOekel as well). Cluster will require an increase in the total number of database connections and seems like a waste given that the server has spare CPU and IO capacity. We don't have the option to replace the output format. And all connections already use chunked output.

Comment: There are no extra database connections if the architecture would be something like this: clusterized 'front' which process requests from clients on the several nodes, business specific processing is called as 'back' is on the single node (if you want this one), for instance, Apache Kafka as data bus between 'front' and 'back' is required.